# Content Security Policy problem with Tailwind CDN on Netlify app hosted

Tags: netlify, content-security-policy

I’m having an issue about CSP rules on my netlify app.

I’m trying to use the CDN from tailwind on my website, and on development it works fine, but when I deploy to netlify, it says the cdn has been blocked by CSP policy.

I already have the CDN URL on the `_headers` file, but it didin’t make any difference at all.

this is how i did the setup my `_headers` file:

```
/*
   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
   Content-Security-Policy: default-src https: 'self' *.netlify.app; connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/* https://google.com/pagead/* https://google.com/ccm/* https:// bat.bing.com/* https://google.com/* https://app-cdn.clickup.com/* https://forms.clickup.com/* *.clarity.ms *.googleadservices.com *.bing.com connect.facebook.net *.facebook.net snap.licdn.com *.ads.linkedin.com *.adsymptotic.com https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/cdn.linkedin.oribi.io * .facebook.com analytics.google.com *.google-analytics.com *.analytics.google.com *.googletagmanager.com *.g.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.google.com.br gap: ws :* *.fontawesome.com *.w3.org cdnjs.cloudflare.com *.cloudfront.net *.amazonaws.com *.ampproject.org bat.bing.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com cdnjs.cloudflare.com *.cloudflare.com; frame-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/ *.google.com *.facebook.com *.bing.com *.youtube.com *.instagram.com; img-src 'self' data: blob: *.facebook.com *.clarity.ms *.linkedin.com *.bing.com snap.licdn.com *. ads.linkedin.com *.adsymptotic.com *.amazonaws.com *.w3.org *.cloudfront.net i.ytimg.com *.google-analytics.com *.analytics.google. with *.googletagmanager.com *.g.doubleclick.net *.google.com *.google.com.br; script-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client https://bat.bing.com/ https://google.com/pagead https://google.com/ccm https: 'self' ' unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.google.com google.com *.cloudfront.net snap.licdn.com analytics.google.com *.bing.com 'unsafe-inline ' https://www.googletagmanager.com; style-src https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/ https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' frame-ancestors 'self';
   Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(), autoplay=(), camera=(), encrypted-media=(), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=*, gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=() , midi=(), payment=(), picture-in-picture=(), sync-xhr=(), usb=()
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   Set-Cookie: HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict;
```

And the error is:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the issue...

its there no problem with the `_headers` file and the CSP config. There was a issue with my service-worker, he was caching my csp , consequently, he was not updating when i edit the file.

I fix removing the caching from the service worker.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your connect-src directive you have listed "https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/cdn.linkedin.oribi.io" which means that cdn.tailwindcss.com is restricted to the path /cdn.linkedin.oribi.io. It should likely be "https://cdn.tailwind.css.com/ [https://cdn.linkedin.oribi.io/"](https://cdn.linkedin.oribi.io/%22), or just the hostnames without scheme and slash.